# Get CSS value of a div from jQuery AJAX call on link click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, transition

I don't think I am the only person who ever asked this, but I can't find a solution that I'm able to understand…

I have a website with a full size background image which should fade out when you click a link whose target page has a different background which will then fade in on load, but should not fade out if it has the same. (or ideally, it should just fade to the new image, but I also haven't found a way to do this smoothly – very new to JS / jquery)

Anyway, I am trying to get the URL from the `background-image` property of the `#background` div on the target page in order to compare with the same element on the current page, like so:

```
  $("#ajaxtestlink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    thisbg = $('#background').css('background-image');
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    whatiwant = $(data).find('#background').css('background-image'));

    // compare both and load next page

  });
});
```

but `whatiwant` returns `undefined`… I have tried playing around with `ajax()`, `get()` and `post()` functions but `$(data).find('#background')` always gives me a w.fn.init thing which I can't really wrap my head around how to access its properties.

What should I be doing? Is there maybe a way simpler solution or a blog post somewhere that I can understand?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `$(data).find('#background')` return?  `console.log($(data).find('#background').length)` should be `1`

Comment: `w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(25)]
length: 0
prevObject: w.fn.init(25) [text, meta, text, meta, text, link, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, style, text, title, text, comment, text, div#background, text, div.panel.main, text, script, text]
__proto__: Object(0)`

Comment: length of 0 means you're not finding any element matching that selector

Comment: I might suggest in this case, rather than making an ajax call to get the page, create a dummy iframe that is 0x0 in dimensions, attach a load event handler to it, and when it's loaded, access the iframe's contentWindow and find what you want.  Rather than trying to stick an entire webpage in a jQuery object, which isn't made for that.

Comment: yeah, it has a length of 0… so am i not using the correct selector? the div is definitely there when i log the whole `data` variable, how would i access it?

Comment: i'll try this approach. (why was my approach not correct? I've found some tutorials that make use of ajax in order to exchange data between pages in similar ways, or at least i thought so…)

Comment: jQuery is meant to be used with the existing page's DOM, or DOM fragments (sub sections of a page).  It's not mean to be used as a complete detached DOM.  There are cases where giving jQuery a complete page will cause it to "eat" parts of the header or other stuff and it will be lost.  Also if you are expecting the elements in the element to have styles in the markup applied to them, I would assume that they would not be applied as the entire element structure is detached and the browser would not have applied the styles to them.

Comment: Further more, if the page you get back from the url has scripts in it, putting those in a jQuery object will cause them to execute with a global eval, which is most likely highly undesirable